# EF Core 5.0 Exception Invalid object name [TableName]

Tags: vb.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

I'm getting an invalid object name error though it's certain the table exists.  It is a VB.NET app being converted from 4.6 to Core 5.  The 4.6 version finds the tables in the database.  There used to be a line of code that initialized the database. It was
Me.Database.SetInitializer(Of MyDbContext)(Nothing)

I cannot find anything equivalent in Core 5.  To resolve the error I have looked at other Q&A here and tried everything under the sun.  Anything else to try?

```
Public Sub New()
        'Original
        'Me.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = sqlConString
        'Me.Database.SetInitializer(Of MyDbContext)(Nothing)

        'New
        Me.Database.EnsureCreated()

    End Sub

    'New
    Protected Overrides Sub OnConfiguring(ByVal ob As DbContextOptionsBuilder)

        If Not ob.IsConfigured Then

            Dim configBuilder As New ConfigurationBuilder()
            configBuilder.SetBasePath(Environment.CurrentDirectory).AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
            Dim configSection As IConfigurationSection = configBuilder.Build().GetSection("AppSettings")

            ob.UseSqlServer(configSection.GetSection("ConnectionString").Value)

        End If

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(ByVal mb As ModelBuilder)

        mb.Entity(Of Store)().ToTable("dbo.Store")
        mb.Entity(Of StoreAttrib)().ToTable("dbo.Store_Attribute")
        mb.Entity(Of GroupStore)().ToTable("dbo.Group_Store")

    End Sub
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Disable migrations?  EF Core is *Very* different from Entity Framework. Instead of trying to get the old code to just run, read the EF Core docs to see how to do what you want. At runtime you need to explicitly [apply migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/applying?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#apply-migrations-at-runtime) with `DbContext.Database.Migrate()`

Comment: If I run the initial migration command on the project it says "The project language VB isnt supported by the built-in IMigrationsCodeGenerator service".  I added the code below but the results are the same:  Public Sub New(ByVal options As DbContextOptions(Of SORContext))
        MyBase.New(options)
        MyBase.Database.Migrate()
    End Sub

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, EF Core does not support VB at this time.  The application had to be converted to C#.